# ImageView doesn't show when layout is on ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have the following layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/second_grey">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:text="@string/sport"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/see_more"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/blue"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="0.99">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">
        <com.favega.groups.SquareLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imgContainer1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:src="@drawable/img_football" />
        </com.favega.groups.SquareLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/football"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgContainer1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">
        <com.favega.groups.SquareLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imgContainer2">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:src="@drawable/img_football" />
        </com.favega.groups.SquareLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/basketball"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgContainer2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">
        <com.favega.groups.SquareLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imgContainer3">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/img3"
                android:src="@drawable/img_football" />
        </com.favega.groups.SquareLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tennis"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgContainer3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I put it in a ListView in this layout:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/categories"></ListView>
```

then, with a simple Adapter, I just set the layout of each element to the layout file.

It looks like this:

[image]

But if I just do  instead of the ListView, it looks like this

[image]

EDIT: Notice the change of Sport for Fútbol, that's just my mistake, it has nothing to do with the actual layout.

EDIT2:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Category category = mList.get(position);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.category, parent, false);
    TextView categoryName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
    categoryName.setText(category.name);
    categoryName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf"));
    return convertView;
}
```

EDIT3:

```
package com.favega.groups;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class SquareLayout extends LinearLayout {

public SquareLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@TargetApi(11)
public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public SquareLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = width > height ? height : width;
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
}
```

}

Comment: can you post `getView` code of your adapter ?

Comment: @kiruwka Done. Ask if you need anything else

Comment: could you please also post your complete category.xml ? Now it contains two roots, so I assume you haven't posted top-level container

Comment: @kiruwka sorry, formatting mistake. Now it should show.

Comment: Everything looks fine so far. I assume the problem might be related to your custom view. Could you post your SquareLayout ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43845/discussion-between-kiruwka-and-zyngawow)

Comment: but you in `getView` you dont set the image resource!!

Comment: @MoshErsan it is already set on the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int size = width > height ? height : width;
setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
```

Clearly you are setting Measured Dimension to the smallest of width and height!
Since you gave width and height as `match_parent`, we can assume that one of the value got as zero from parent. As your intention is to make a square image, I prefer you relate this `SquareLayout` to the child(image) itself rather that the parent. By using `wrap_content`.

Comment: Yes, just a square image.

Comment: Then instead of relating to the parent, did you try to relate to the image itself? ie, instead of `match_parent`, use `wrap_content' for the squareLayout xml

Comment: You got it! Someone else in the chat got it too. Instead of having a SquareLayout, I made a SquareImageView, so that I at least remove some components.

Comment: Glad that it helped. So you need a white square with image and text in it.

Comment: No, it's only the image that needs to be square. The actual card has to be a rectangle, but the image is square. Anyways, what was wrong was my onMeasure

Answer (score 0):

Set each tag of view in `converView.setTag(viewName);` before returning covertView.

Try May help.Thanks!!